# Using Mongoose date schema

Tags: mongoose

This is my schema:

```
var commentSchema= new Schema({
    text:String,
    author: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }],
    username : String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

When I print the date, it prints something like

> Sun Apr 01 2018 08:22:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)

How can I reduce it to something like

> Sun Apr 01,2018

Answer (score 1):

In that case mongoose result should be auto-converted to the type that is set in schema, in your case it's Date object.

When you try to "print" it JS auto-converts it to string.

Suppose you have comments model, then:

```
comments.find({}).exec((err, data) => {
  let d = data.date; // It's Date object
  console.log(d.getMonth() + ' ' + d.getYear()); // check docs to get format you need
})
```

Take a look at available functions on object ([Javascript native Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date))